# Shantyboat communities on the upper Mississippi River Valley

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, 19th-century

Does anyone have links or resources beyond books they can direct me to that directly deal with shantyboat communities along the banks of the Mississippi River north of St. Louis, Missouri?

I'm interested in exploring, gathering, and archiving oral history around people living on or adjacent to the river.

I've already examined many of the memoirs of people living or traveling in shantyboats in the late 19th up to the mid 20th century. (Which are highly entertaining, by the way.)

And of course I've googled the most obvious resources:

```
+(shantyboat OR houseboat OR boathouse) mississippi river
 1800..1980 (minnesota OR wisconsin OR illinois OR iowa OR missouri)
 -rental -cruises
```

Any further suggestions or people I should check in with?

An aside: I don't have the rep to create likely tags, so if you can, feel free: mississippi-river oral-history houseboat communities commons

Comment: Well, there's a reason for (modest) rep restrictions on things like creating tags. If you think you have a good case for those tags, I'd suggest bringing it up in our meta.

Answer (score 5):

I not only found this book:  [The Floating Boathouses on the Upper Mississippi River: Their History, Their Stories](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0578002051)

but managed to meet the author who has a boathouse in Brownsville, MN when I floated through on [my research journey.](http://peoplesriverhistory.us)